# Same JAR compiled against diff JDK versions

Tags: java, maven, java-11, maven-profiles

We have a legacy Java lib (referred to as AcmeLib) that is used to bootstrap Java applications, provide config, wrap certain db functionality and such like. This lib is v much in maintenance mode, and is a standard Java 8 jars built using maven.

We now want to build Java 11 apps - and they need to use AcmeLib. My first thought is to just continue to build AcmeLib in Java 8 - and it will work just fine when imported into Java 11 apps (* where the key thing is to update the AcmeLib dependencies).

I have another idea to build a Java 8 AND Java 11 version of AcmeLib. I can do this with a maven profile (as they only diff between the libs will be the pom stuff, e.g. plugin configs, etc.) e.g.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java-11</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>11</jdk>
        </activation>
        <!-- add Java 11 specific configuration -->
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

So 2 profiles, means 2 builds - so my questions (about time!) is I'm wondering if this is perhaps an anti-pattern? Also, have people any suggestions around naming conventions? The current lib version is arbitrarily on 5.5, so I could create an 11 version for example..

```
<!--  Java 8 complied -->
<artifactId>AcmeLib</artifactId>
<version>5.6</version>

<!--  Java 11 complied -->
<artifactId>AcmeLib</artifactId>
<version>11</version>
```

Comment: Well, if the lib can be built using Java 8 and it doesn't have any dependencies that differ between Java versions then I'd just use the Java 8 version - it should be fully compatible with a Java 11 VM. IMO there's no need to provide 2 versions of the same thing which only differ in the class version - in the end this will only cause confusion.

Comment: @Thomas unless that library uses some internal JDK classes which were made unavailable for external code base using concept of modules

Comment: @Ivan yes, that's part of what I meant by "dependencies that differ between Java versions" :)

Comment: Than you have to offer two different resulting artifact where one is build against first one (JDK 8) and a second which is build against the second one (JDK 11)...no other way is possible which means you need to create two separate artifacts which means multi module build producing different artifacts..